# Best way to scrape a set of pages with mixed content

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

I’m trying to show a list of lunch venues around the office with their today’s menus. But the problem is the websites that offer the lunch menus, don’t always offer the same kind of content.

For instance, some of the websites offer a nice JSON output. [Look at this one](http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/output/daily_json/57/2015/07/21/fi), it offers the English/Finnish course names separately and everything I need is available. There are couple of others like this.

But others, don’t always have a nice output. [Like this one](http://www.keilaniemi.fi/lounasravintola/think/). The content is laid out in plain HTML and English and Finnish food names are not exactly ordered. Also food properties like (L, VL, VS, G, etc) are just normal text like the food name.

What, in your opinion, is the best way to scrape all these available data in different formats and turn them into usable data? I tried to make a scraper with Node.js (& phantomjs, etc) but it only works with one website, and it’s not that accurate in case of the food names.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like [kimonolabs.com](https://www.kimonolabs.com/), they are much easier to use and they give you APIs to update your side.
Remember that they are best for tabular data contents.

Answer (score 1):

There my be simple algorithmic solutions to the problem, If there is a list of all available food names this can be really helpful, you find the  occurrence of a food name inside a document (for today).

If there is not any food list, You may use TF/IDF. TF/IDF allows to calculate the score of a word inside a document among the current document and also other documents. But this solution needs enough data to work.

I think the best solution is some thing like this:

1. Creating a list of all available websites that should be scrapped.
2. Writing driver classes for each website data.
3. Each driver has the duty of creating the general domain entity from its standard document.

If you can use PHP, [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) along with [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) would be a great choice. These two will provide a jQuery like path finder and a nice wrapper arround HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You are touching really difficult problem. Unfortunately there are no easy solutions.

Actually there are two different parts to solve:

1. data scraping from different sources
2. data integration

Let's start with first problem - data scraping from different sources. In my projects I usually process data in several steps. I have dedicated scrapers for all specific sites I want, and process them in the following order:

1. fetch raw page (unstructured data)
2. extract data from page (unstructured data)
3. extract, convert and map data into page-specific model (fully structured data)
4. map data from fully structured model to common/normalized model

Steps 1-2 are scraping oriented and steps 3-4 are strictly data-extraction / data-integration oriented.

While you can easily implement steps 1-2 relatively easy using your own webscrapers or by utilizing existing web services - data integration is the most difficult part in your case. You will probably require some machine-learning techniques (shallow, domain specific Natural Language Processing) along with custom heuristics.

In case of such a messy input like [this one](http://www.keilaniemi.fi/lounasravintola/think/) I would process lines separately and use some dictionary to get rid Finnish/English words and analyse what has left. But in this case it will never be 100% accurate due to possibility of human-input errors.

I am also worried that you stack is not very well suited to do such tasks. For such processing I am utilizing Java/Groovy along with integration frameworks (Mule ESB / Spring Integration) in order to coordinate data processing.

In summary: it is really difficult and complex problem. I would rather assume less input data coverage than aiming to be 100% accurate (unless it is really worth it).